# circles detected inconsistent in still video in opencv

Tags: video, opencv, detection, geometry

I was wondering what the cause is for circles to be detected sometimes and not other times in a still video where the circles dont move. Is it to do with quality of video?

Answer (score 1):

Probably - it depends on the method you are using to search for them.

The most common problem is differences in lighting, your eyes don't notice a gradual chnage in background but any algorithm that is looking for a certain signal level is very sensitive to even lighting unless you take steps to adjust for it.